# Cannot find type definition file for 'node' even after properly adding config in tsconfig.json and install of @types/node in Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting the error event adding in tsconfig.json

```
  "types":["node"],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types/" ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eLba.png)

I tried multiple ways,

Used versions:

```
"@types/node": "^16.18.38",
 "typescript": "^5.1.6"
```

Node version  : 16.19.1`

Comment: I am just now seeing the same thing. Any idea if something changed in Angular?